# Fix the order of X label when using mutate function and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to create text-based heatmap using tidyverse package. Though I was able to produce the heatmap, the X labels are not arranged as provided in my data.

I would like to have the X labels just as I provide. While I did find a few solutions, somehow I was not able to apply them in my code. I also don't want to hard code the columns in factor functions. The code is as below:

```
df <- read.table('Mydata_sheet_test.txt', sep="\t", header=TRUE)
df %>% 
  gather(col, Value, -Sample_names) %>% 
  mutate(row = factor(Sample_names, levels = rev(unique(Sample_names))),
         Value = factor(Value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(col, row, fill = Value)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="black") + 
  labs(x = "Chromosome names", y = "samples") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=21,vjust=0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")
```

PS: I am still going through the dplyr and basics of data manipulation, My apologies if there is any simple solution and I missed it.

Main code courtesy: Maurits Evers

My data looks like this:
sample_ID,C1.P,C1.Q,C2.P,C2.Q,C3.P,C3.Q,C4.P,C4.Q,C10.P,C10.Q,C20.P,C20.Q

sam000086,TLM,TLM,TLM,TLM,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp

sam000046,,,,,,,,,,,,

sam000028,,,,,,,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,,

sam000092,,3 cp,TLM,TLM,TLM,TLM,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,TLM,TLM

sam000080,,3 cp,TLM,TLM,,,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp,3 cp

........so on

Comment: Hi can you add some sample data to work with?

Comment: hi @scientific_explorer I've added the data sample along....the num of cols and num of rows both varies each time handle these sheets.

Comment: I replicated your code. The x axis labels right now are ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4. Do you want to change that to custom axis labels?

Comment: @scientific_explorer...I have provided an instance of my actual data in the original post above..now i think the problem will pop up with you too...I basically want the order of columns to remain just as seen in the above data....but in the plot after C1.p C1.q , C10.p C10.q appears which is not in the data !!!

Comment: C10.p and C10.q are there in your data. Do you mean to say that they aren't in the order you want? ie. C1.p, C1.q, C2.p, C2.q, ... and so on?

Comment: yes...exactly...the order,as seen in the data, is not preserved in the plot

Comment: if you have the library tidyverse, just change `ggplot(aes(col, row, fill = Value))` to `ggplot(aes(as_factor(col), row, fill = Value))`. This will help

Comment: If you don't want to install `tidyverse` then you can do what you want with this `ggplot(aes(factor(col, levels = unique(col)), row, fill = Value))`

Comment: You the man !!!...Please convert it as answer so I can accept it ...thereby I hope will be easier for other people to reference in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ggplot(aes(col, row, fill = Value))` to `ggplot(aes(as_factor(col), row, fill = Value))` if you have `tidyverse` or `forcats`.

Else change it to `ggplot(aes(factor(col, levels = unique(col)), row, fill = Value))`.